# Relations with mongoose and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have been looking for a way to relate a collection that has an array of objects, each object belongs to a different user, I would not like to force my backend by making it extract manually through maps or reduce the ids that belong to each user, I would like to know if is there a way to use populate so that only matching ids are added to my list

So far I have not been able to find information about it, I hope someone can help me

Comment: please elaborate how does your documents look and what exactly you want to query.

Answer (score 0):

you can you aggregate pipeline

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String
});

const collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 userIds: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Collection = mongoose.model('Collection', collectionSchema);

Collection.aggregate([
{
 $lookup: {
   from: 'users',
   localField: 'userIds',
   foreignField: '_id',
   as: 'users'
  }
}
```

]).exec((err, collections) => {
if (err) throw err;

```
console.log(collections);
});
```